# JMeter: how to trigger all multiple requests at same time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have defined a few samplers in JMeter.

I want to trigger all those samplers at same time.
Example: Say, I have 5 users and 5 samplers. I want each sampler is triggered at same time by each of user. This is the scenario.

How can I simulate this scenario using Jmeter?

Comment: I have scenario where I have to run multiple JDBC request using csv files for each JDBC request.How can I do this.Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You would need 2 Thread Groups (TG).

Make sure that "Run Thread Groups consecutively" under your test plan is UNCHECKED else you'll be having 2nd TG running after 1st TG.

Answer (score 7):

Your scenario is,

```
5 Users hitting 5 URLs(samplers) simultaneously.
```

So what you need to do is, in your **Test Plan**, add **5 Thread Groups**. In each Thread Group configure the number of **Threads to 5** and **Ramp Up to 0**.

Now, add **one HTTP Request sampler** in each **Thread Group**. Configure each sampler according to the URL you want to test.

Add **Listener(s)** to your **Test Plan**. Save the Test Plan and Run your test.

**Make sure you haven't selected the "Run Thread Groups consecutively" in the Test Plan.**

Comment: This scheme does not seem to scale well, what if I need to have 500 Simultaneous users, in that case, do I need to configure 500 Thread Groups?

Comment: Individual thread groups aren't for each individual user. In Jmeter to generate a load of 500 users you need set up Threads within the Thread Group as 500. Threads represents users in Jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute the same sampler simultaneously for a few users you have to put sampler into [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

Comment: No, I want to execute different samplers simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

You should add multiple "Thread Group" into a "Test Plan". Inside "Test Plan"  unselect "Run thread groups consecutively".

Inside every "Thread Group" configure "Number of Threads(users)" as "5",  "Ramp-Up Period" as "0", "Loop Count" as "1".

For 5 Samplers you should need 5 "Thread Group". Now, add 1 "HTTP Request" into each "Thread Group".

Configure Every "HTTP Request".

Now add "View Results Tree" as a listener into a "Test Plan". 
Now run the Test plan.

[example of sending multiple requests at the same time to do a concurrent testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzihn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parallel Controller plugin in JMeter, created by Blazemeter for JMeter.
Please [refer this link for more info.](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md)